# Python script with Numpy import running in VS Code but not in terminal

Tags: python, windows, visual-studio-code, terminal, pip

I can run a Python file when I click "Run Python File" in top right of Visual Studio Code. But when run in terminal, I get an error:

```py
import numpy as np
```

```py
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'numpy'
```

How can I solve this? I tried using the command `pip install numpy`, but still get the error.

Comment: probably your `pip` and `python` commands refer to different installations. Try installing numpy with `python -m pip install numpy` instead.

Comment: @matszwecja thank you, but still not work :<
D:\Machine Learning\Machine-Learning-A-Z-Udemy - Working>python PerceptronLearningAlgorithm.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\Machine Learning\Machine-Learning-A-Z-Udemy - Working\PerceptronLearningAlgorithm.py", line 3, in <module>
    import numpy as np
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'numpy'

D:\Machine Learning\Machine-Learning-A-Z-Udemy - Working>pip -m install numpy

Usage:
  pip <command> [options]

no such option: -m

Comment: `pip -m install numpy` - That's not the command I wrote.

Answer (score 0):

> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'numpy'

You can run the commands `pip install numpy` in your terminal to install the module.